# Transition position: relative's top property causes relayout and jumping in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

When running the following code in IE11 the "items" start jittering around, and the page undergoes relayout (even though position: relative shouldn't change the layout).

The interesting parts involved:

```
content > article > a {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: top ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

content > article >a:hover {
    top: -0.375vw;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
}
```

The full runnable code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Some site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            padding: 0.375vw;
        }

        content {
            font-size: 0;
        }

        content > article {
            display: inline-block;
            box-sizing: border-box;

            width: 50%;
            padding: 0.375vw;
        }

        content > article > a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            transition: top ease-in-out 0.3s;
            
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        content > article > a > span {
            display: block;
            
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 1280px;
            height: 548px;

            background-color: grey;
        }

        content > article > a > header {
            display: block;
            box-sizing: border-box;

            width: 100%;
            height: 2.25vw;
            padding: 0.375vw 0.75vw;

            line-height: 1.5vw;
            font-size: 1.5vw;

            background-color: #3a3a3a;
        }

        content > article > a:hover {
            top: -0.375vw;
            transition-duration: 0.15s;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <content>
        <article>
            <a href="#">
                <span></span>
                <header>Item 1</header>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article>
            <a href="#">
                <span></span>
                <header>Item 2</header>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article>
            <a href="#">
                <span></span>
                <header>Item 3</header>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article>
            <a href="#">
                <span></span>
                <header>Item 4</header>
            </a>
        </article>
    </content>
</body>

</html>
```

Anybody knows why this is happening, and more importantly, how to fix it?